# Not able to remove NOODP tag from wordpress site

Tags: noindex

My blog site is not indexed in Google. I am using yoast SEO plugin (free version). I have unchecked the option of NOODP still its showing in the source code. And in search console its showing 'noindex' detected in 'robots' meta ta, Though there are no noindex tag. URL is https://blog.skillsz.com/.. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Your Yoast SEO plugin version is outdated. If you update your plugin to the latest version, at this moment 17.2.1, your issue will be resolved.

There was an issue resolved in version 4.6 that affects your version, see this github issue for details: https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/6843

Comment: Thank you so much..will try